# MySQL: Copy a field to another table

Tags: mysql, copy

I have a table `posts` that could look like this:

```
  id  |  title  |  body  |  created  | ..
-------------------------------------------
```

I would like to use the boolean search feature that is offered by a MyISAM Table, but the `posts` table is InnoDB. So I created another table 'post_contents' that looks like this:

```
  post_id  |  body
--------------------
```

That table is already filled with some contents and I can use the boolean search. However, I need to move the title field in the post_contents table as well and then copy the existing title-data to the new field.

I know about the INSERT .. SELECT syntax, but I don't seem to be able to create the correct query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way:

I copied the the `post_contents` table to `pc` and truncated the existing data in `post_contents`. Then I used that query

```
INSERT INTO post_contents (post_id, title, body, created, modified) 
SELECT post.id, post.title, pc.body, pc.draft, pc.created, pc.modified 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN pc ON post.id = pc.post_id
```

Maybe that is helpful for other people :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
insert into post_contents (post_id, body) select id, body from posts;
```

Or is the post_id column in the post_contents table generated differently?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I just tried that, but i get a `#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`
The body field does already exist and is filled in the new table (I want to add the title field), so I probably need an UPDATE query?!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't tell from your question that the second table already had data that you had to match up to.

Comment: my bad .. I have difficulties to express myself in english :) Your answer still led me in the right direction -> thanks